# Automatically log user in as Guest in web2py

Tags: python, authentication, web2py

I'd like to set up a guest account on my web2py app, and automatically log users in as Guest if they choose not to make their own account. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How is being logged in as Guest supposed to differ from simply not being logged in?

Comment: The game site I'm building requires a character to be assigned to a user; I want people to be able to play without making an account, but I need a user to assign the character to, and to have auth.user exist even without logging in.

Comment: With a single guest account, it sounds like you could have a problem if each guest is supposed to have a different character. Rather than faking a login via the Auth system, why not store the relevant character data in the session (without an account, the user's game/data could not persist beyond the current session anyway)? Character data could also go in a separate character database table, with an optional link to the auth_user table for users with accounts.

Comment: That's a very good idea, actually. Just store the char data as a dict in ``session``, and if the user is logged in, write to the character db when the game is saved (which only happens if it's logged in). OK i will do that!